# Apache2: No Effect Of ErrorLogFormat

Tags: apache, http, logging, apache2.4

i changed ErrorLogFormat at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but the this doesn't effect the log. I also added my ErrorLogFormat to the config files in the sites-enabled directory, but no effect.

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t] [%l] [client %a] %M"
```

This is the log:

```
[Sat Oct 13 13:01:56 2018] [error] [client 123.123.123.123:41204] AH01790: user `asd' in realm `some realm' not found: /
```

EDIT: It's running on a rasperry pi updated. I tested: stop and start, restart on the apache service and system reboot.

```
grep -r "ErrorLogFormat" /etc/apache2
```

revealed only the desired format, that i added at apache.conf and the conf files at sites-enabled.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?  Not graceful, a full stop - start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tested it now, but no success. See my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache 2.4 (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlogformat), you can use:

```
ErrorLogFormat "[%{cu}t] [%l] [client %a] %M"
```

`%{cu}t`: The current time in compact ISO 8601 format, including micro-seconds

In the log file it will show:

> [2018-10-14 10:31:05.273482] [debug] [client AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 4296 for (localhost)

The date format is the same as what you want, without having to specify all the rules you have.

---

If you use `%{u}t`, the log format becomes:

> [Sun Oct 14 10:30:31.944078 2018] [info] [client ::1:47376] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/mbert/tools/apache/htdocs/so/oij

which is what you had previously.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Ok now i see that ErrorLogFormat has different rules than LogFormat. by the way, you got my upvote, but its not public cause im new :)

Comment: @Nic3500 can you guess why `%a` would show up blank? It's supposed to be the client IP address. I [posted a question](https://serverfault.com/q/981195/161152) about that.